# Nested result in JSON format

Tags: peewee

Please,

How can I use a query with Peewee to return a JSON format with Nested objects?

## Example:

```
[
  {
    "active": 1, 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Los Angeles",
    "idState": 2,
    "TBState": {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "California"                
     }
  }
]
```

I can it using SqlAlchemy using relationship by model but in Peewee I don't know as make.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Peewee has a helper `model_to_dict` [docs](http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#model_to_dict) that you can use.